# Can't orthogonally diagonalise this symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthogonality

So I have a symmetric matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & -4 \\ 2 & -1 & -2 \\ -4 & -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and I want to orthogonally diagonalise it. I know that there are eigenvalues $-2$ and $7$ (-2 with an algebraic multiplicity of two, and a basis $$\left\{{\pmatrix{1\\0\\2}},{\pmatrix{0\\1\\1}}\right\}$$ I, so far, haven't been able to find:

- the eigenvector corresponding to 7  (I know from online calculators that it is in fact $\begin{array}{c} 2 \\1\\-2 \end{array}$), but the matrix (A - -7$\lambda$) = $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & -4 \\ 2 & -1 & -2 \\ -4 & -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ which row reduces down (as calculated online) to $$A = \begin{bmatrix}{} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ which gives $x = 2y = -z$, which leads to a vector $\begin{array}{c} 1 \\2\\-1 \end{array}$ or similar.
- how to correctly orthonormalize the vectors (by using Pythagoras geometrically, or by Gram-Schmidt?)
  and therefore I can't orthogonally diagonalise A.

Comment: Your eigenvector for $\lambda = 7$ should be $(2,1,-2)^T$

Comment: Your vectors for $\lambda = -2$ should be something like $\{(1,0,1),(0,2,1)\}$, and you should apply Gram Schmidt to this basis.

Comment: So, it seems that you have a few computational errors.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know what the eigenvector for 7 should be, I just don't know how to get it. For -2, aren't my vectors row-equivalent? Gram-Schmidt produces (1,0,2)^T and (-2/5,1,1/5)^T (I think.)

Comment: Your equations $x=2y=-z$ for the eigenvector with eigenvalue $7$ have the general solution $(2y,y,-2y)^\top=y(2,1,-2)^\top$.  I don't know where you got "$(1,2,-1)^\top$ or similar".

Comment: (1,2,−1)⊤ is from row-reduction, @AndreasBlass. At least I think so? I couldn't rr by hand so I used http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/matrices-calculators/matrix-calculator.php

Comment: As others have noted, your eigenvectors are all wrong. You can check whether you in fact have eigenvectors by multiplying them by the matrix; if they are eigenvectors, this should multiply them by the eigenvalue.

When you do have the correct eigenvectors, there's no need to orthogonalize the ones for different eigenvalues -- they are necessarily orthogonal to each other for a square matrix. You only need to othogonalize them within each eigenspace.

Comment: Also your eigenvalue shouldn't be 7, it should be 17.

Comment: 17? How - what... Please explain?

Comment: Well, $(1,2,-1)^\top$ is not a solution of $x=2y$ nor of $2y=-z$, because $1\neq2\cdot2$ and $2\cdot2\neq-(-1)$.  So I suggest you abandon whatever source gave you this incorrect answer and learn how to solve such equations yourself.  (I don't mean to accuse the source of being wrong; maybe you misinterpreted what it told you, or maybe you asked the question incorrectly.  But in any case, this equation is easier to solve by inspection than by web.)

Comment: The charpoly is -(2-lambda)^2(7 - lambda), isn't it?

Comment: -God- (the assignment) told me that 7 is an eigenvalue definitely.

Comment: Sorted the eigenvector issue.

Comment: @JoshuaSoong sorry about the 17 bit; I had made a computational error myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are only eigenvalues $-2$ and $7$, then you can eliminate those with eigenvalue $-2$ and be left with the others. This is done by considering
$$
          (A+2I) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 4 & 2 & -4 \\ 2 & 1 & -2 \\ -4 & -2 & 4\end{array}\right]
$$
The columns have to be eigevectors with eigenvalue $7$. There is only one independent column, which is what you expect:
$$
                     \left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 1 \\ -2\end{array}\right],\;\;\;\;
          A \left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 1 \\ -2\end{array}\right]
           = \left[\begin{array}{c}14 \\ 7 \\ -14\end{array}\right]
           = 7\left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 1 \\ -2\end{array}\right]
$$

Now consider the case for eigenvalue $-2$:
$$
          (A-7I) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} -5 & 2 & -4 \\ 2 & -8 & -2 \\ -4 & -2 & -5\end{array}\right]
$$
The column space is two-dimensional; it's obviously not one-dimensional, and you can easily check that the columns are orthogonal to the eigenvector with eigenvalue $7$ given above. So everything checks. If you add the first and the third columns, you find that the following is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-2$:
$$
               \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right],
$$
and this one is orthogonal to the middle column. So an orthogonal basis of the eigenspace with eigenvalue $-2$ is
$$
               \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array},\right]
       \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -4 \\ -1 \end{array}\right]\right\}
$$
If you normalize the column vectors, then you get the required orthogonal change of basis matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}AU=D=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}7 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{array}\right]$ is a diagonal matrix. The matrix $U$ is
$$
           U = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
                        2/3 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{18}  \\
                        1/3 & 0 &  -4/\sqrt{18} \\
                        -2/3 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{18}
                       \end{array}\right]
$$
The matrix $U$ is orthogonal, which means $U^{-1}=U^{T}$.